# git credential approve does not work for Jenkins pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, credentials

In my Jenkins pipeline I have following code:

```
stage('pushing'){
    steps {
        withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: '91f32d3c-b7ee-49ac-b233-3bd93d2696eb', passwordVariable: 'GIT_PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'GIT_USERNAME')]) {
            sh("echo -e 'url=https://domain.tld\nusername=${GIT_USERNAME}\npassword=${GIT_PASSWORD}' | git credential approve")
            sh('git push --tags')
        }
    }
}
```

The output looks as follows:

```
[Pipeline] sh
13:28:52 [git-push-tag] Running shell script
13:28:52 + git push --tags
13:28:52 fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://domain.tld/scm/~user/git-push-app.git/'
```

I have already prepared environment with minimal configuration:

```
git config --global user.name jenkins
git config --global user.email jenkins@domain.tld
git config --global credential.helper cache
git config --global push.default simple
```

With the above configuration **git credential approve** and **git push --tags** from command line works for me. But that does not work in Jenkins pipeline.

I don't have any idea why.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a matter of quotes, the env vars such as `${GIT_USERNAME}` are not interpolated because of single quotes surrounding the string.

```
            sh("echo -e 'url=https://domain.tld\nusername=${GIT_USERNAME}\npassword=${GIT_PASSWORD}' | git credential approve")
fixed below:
            sh('echo -e "url=https://domain.tld\nusername=${GIT_USERNAME}\npassword=${GIT_PASSWORD}" | git credential approve')
```